# Adding a Short Circuit Alarm to a Power Supply

Tags: power-supply, short-circuit

We have a lab type 3 channel bench power supply. (2 adjustable channels and a 5V channel.) It already has short circuit protection on it. Although I want to add a buzzer alarm when the short circuit protection is active. It just has an indicator LED, and sometimes students won't realize that they short circuited the channel. All three channels have the protection independently. So I can feed the alarm from the 5V channel when one of the other two channels has a short circuit.

My question is how to trigger the alarm?

Power Supply Front Panel:
[image]

Comment: I don't see any signs of short circuit protection there. Do you mean the current limit feature? You probably don't want to make it buzz in case of current limit being triggered, because then you can't use them as constant current sources anymore.

Comment: I'd say that the students need to learn **not** to short the outputs. And if they do, the supply can handle it right? Electronics is full of things to "not do", I mean a small signal transistor is easily damaged when handled incorrectly. There is already a CC indicator so they need to know what it means when that lights up.

Comment: That's basically what I want to do. When the CC indicator lights up, I want it to buzz at the same time to warn them.

Comment: So if the voltage across the output is less than let's say 0.3V buzz, that should be pretty easy to do

Comment: Ask them what is the worst thing that could happen if they ignored traffic lights at high speed?  How safe is it? well that depends. Then watch out for all indicators.  If they fail to observe this, remind them that engineers are expected to pay attention to all details.  Can you be more effective than opening up the $1000 instrument apart and guessing where to attach a 5V Piezo buzzer?